# How to change the brightness after starting and  stopping the service in  Android?

Tags: android

In my application, when i am starting the Broad Cast Reciever, i am putting the phone in Dim Mode. For this i am using the below code:

```
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 0);
```

Before that, i am storing the previous brightness using Shared Preference and when i am stopping my application, i am changing the brightness to the previous stored brightness.

```
 float brightness = myPrefs.getFloat("previous_bright", 0.0f);
                    android.provider.Settings.System.putFloat(context.getContentResolver(),android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
```

Now it is going to the dim mode. But when i am stopping the application, first i have to press the power button of the device and then i have to unlock it. Then only it is changing to its previous brightness. I am checking it in Google Nexus One. How an i change it without locking and unlocking it??

My OS version is 2.2. And it is coming fine in Android Tablet(Olive Pad).

Comment: Your question is unclear

Comment: I my application, i can start one service in a particular time.So when that time will reach, i will set one wallpaper in the phone's Home Screen and phone will go in dim mode. And when i am reaching to a particular time, my service will stop and it should go to the previous brightness which i stored already. But this changes is not happening until i am not pressing the power button of the phone.

Comment: Now when the service is starting, after that if i press the power button and unlock the home screen, then it is coming in the dim mode.

Comment: Do you want to control brightness when screen is locked?

Comment: No. Its not depends on screen is locked or unlocked. When my service will start, brightness should be like zero. And when my service stopped, it should go back to its previous brightness.